# Android encryption database

Tags: java, android, database, encryption

I search a solution for encrypt a database in Android. 
I know that exist a library as name SQLCipher but that library doesn't work for version upper than Android 4.1 that's why i ask you for an other library that encrypt a database or a solution for make that (i know i can encrypt my string data one by one but i search for encrypt the entire database like in SQLCipher). If possible give me a sample that used your library or your solution that was all time better than a big explanation :).

Thanks in advance for your solution.

Comment: I don't think so, i just developed a hardly encrypting app. My first choice would by to write something like a proxy for database access which handels to encrypted and decrypted value by value. But pay attantion, you will not by able to search on the database anymore. Only on not encrypted values.

Comment: Yes you have true if i encrypt value by value i can't search in my DB thats why i search to encrypt the entire database like in SQLCipher if only SQLCipher work for Android 4.2 and 4.3...

Comment: I would try to figure out if i can get access to the SQLLite file of my app and if you can encrypt this file. If possible you could write something that decrypts the SQLLite file on start and encrypting it on app stop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally solution is to used SQLCipher and thats work fine for all Android for saw why thats not work in my case just look this post [Android error with sqlcipher on version android 4.2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18076109/android-error-with-sqlcipher-on-version-android-4-2-2)

Answer (score 1):

> I know that exist a library as name SQLCipher but that library doesn't work for version upper than Android 4.1

This is incorrect. It works perfectly fine on Android 4.2 and 4.3. In fact, I just tested two of my SQLCipher for Android samples on a Nexus 10 running Android 4.3 while typing up this answer, and I had no problems.

Comment: Oh good news so tell me what is the version of your SQLCipher please. Cause my project worked fine in 4.0.4 (in galaxy s3) and crash in 4.2.2 (galaxy s4) with an SQLException ("not an error"). And in web site of SQLCipher i found in history that works in 4.1 but no release since. If you have an answer for resolved my problem I will be very grateful

Comment: @user1770436: "what is the version of your SQLCipher please" -- the latest (2.2.1). "i found in history that works in 4.1 but no release since" -- third-party libraries do not need to be updated every time that Android itself gets an new API level.

Comment: I tried the 2.2.1 but that not fixed my problem that continu to work in 4.0.4 and not in 4.2.2 problem become from this line new net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase(path, password, (net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory) factory,
     flags, databaseHook);

Comment: @user1770436: Perhaps you should consider opening a new StackOverflow question, with the code and the stack trace. These projects work fine on Android 4.3: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Database/ConstantsSecure https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Database/PasswordBox

Comment: I have an other StackOverflow question here is the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18076109/android-error-with-sqlcipher-on-version-android-4-2-2 if you want more information for help i can give you (in real i made a fusion of project GreenDAO and SQLCipher). Thanks for your consideration i go look the project and check diference with my project.